# Use svg as icon with D3 and htmlwidgets

Tags: d3.js, htmlwidgets

I was able to create my first htmlwidget that creates this animated plot:

[image]

I would like to replace the "B" and "D" buttons with a single icon that uses an svg as the icon. In particular, I want to use [this icon.](https://thenounproject.com/term/bell-curve/614251/). The icon should be black when selected, light gray when unselected, and a darker gray when hovering over.

To start, I'm not sure where to save the file so my code can see it.

This is the yaml for my htmlwidget package:

```
# (uncomment to add a dependency)
 dependencies:
  - name: D3
    version: 4
    src: htmlwidgets/lib/D3
    script: d3.v4.js
    stylesheet: style.css
  - name: d3tip
    version: 0.7.1
    src: htmlwidgets/lib/d3-tip
    script: d3-tip.min.js
    stylesheet: style.css
```

And this is the js file:

```
HTMLWidgets.widget({

  name: 'IMPosterior',

  type: 'output',

  factory: function(el, width, height) {

    // TODO: define shared variables for this instance

    return {

      renderValue: function(opts) {

        //transition
        var transDuration = 1000;

        var dataDiscrete = opts.bars.map((b, i) => {
            b.y = Number(b.y);
            b.desc = opts.text[i];
            return b;
        });

        var distParams = {
            min: d3.min(opts.data, d => d.x),
            max: d3.max(opts.data, d => d.x)
        };

        distParams.cuts = [-opts.MME, opts.MME, distParams.max];

        opts.data = opts.data.sort((a,b) => a.x - b.x);

        var dataContinuousGroups = [];
        distParams.cuts.forEach((c, i) => {
            let data = opts.data.filter(d => {
                if (i === 0) {
                    return d.x < c;
                } else if (i === distParams.cuts.length - 1) {
                    return d.x > distParams.cuts[i - 1];
                } else {
                    return d.x < c && d.x > distParams.cuts[i - 1];
                }
            });

            data.unshift({x:data[0].x, y:0});
            data.push({x:data[data.length - 1].x, y:0});

            dataContinuousGroups.push({
                color: opts.colors[i],
                data: data
            });
        });

        var margin = {
                top: 50,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 80,
                left: 70
            },
            dims = {
                width: width - margin.left - margin.right,
                height: height - margin.top - margin.bottom
            };

        var xContinuous = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([distParams.min - 1, distParams.max + 1])
            .range([0, dims.width]);

        var xDiscrete = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(dataDiscrete.map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
            .rangeRound([0, dims.width]).padding(0.1);

        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, 1])
            .range([dims.height, 0]);

        var svg = d3.select(el).append("svg")
            .attr("width", dims.width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", dims.height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

        var g = svg
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
            .scale(xDiscrete);

        var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
            .scale(y)
            .ticks(10)
            .tickFormat(d3.format(".0%"));

        var yLabel = g.append("text")
            .attr("class", "y-axis-label")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", -52)
            .attr("x", -160)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .style("font-size", 14 + "px")
            .text("Probability");

        g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + dims.height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);

        var areas = g.selectAll(".area")
            .data(dataDiscrete)
            .enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", "area")
                .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
                .attr("d", function(d, i) {
                    let numPts = dataContinuousGroups[i].data.length - 2;
                    var path = d3.path()
                    path.moveTo(xDiscrete(d.x), y(0));
                    for (j=0; j<numPts; j++) {
                        path.lineTo(xDiscrete(d.x) + j*xDiscrete.bandwidth()/(numPts-1), y(d.y))
                    }
                    path.lineTo(xDiscrete(d.x) + xDiscrete.bandwidth(), y(0));
                    return path.toString();
                });

        var tooltip = d3.tip()
            .attr('class', 'd3-tip chart-data-tip')
            .offset([30, 0])
            .direction('s')
            .html(function(d, i) {
                return "<span>" + dataDiscrete[i].desc + "</span>";
            });

        g.call(tooltip);

        areas
            .on('mouseover', tooltip.show)
            .on('mouseout', tooltip.hide);

        var thresholdLine = g.append("line")
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .style("stroke-width", "1.5px")
            .style("stroke-dasharray", "5,5")
            .style("opacity", 1)
            .attr("x1", 0)
            .attr("y1", y(opts.threshold))
            .attr("x2", dims.width)
            .attr("y2", y(opts.threshold));


        var updateXAxis = function(type, duration) {
            if (type === "continuous") {
                xAxis.scale(xContinuous);
            } else {
                xAxis.scale(xDiscrete);
            }
            d3.select(".x").transition().duration(duration).call(xAxis);       
        };

        var updateYAxis = function(data, duration) {
            var extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
                return d.y;
            });
            extent[0] = 0;
            extent[1] = extent[1] + 0.2*(extent[1] - extent[0]);
            y.domain(extent);
            d3.select(".y").transition().duration(duration).call(yAxis);
        };

        var toggle = function(to, duration) {
            if (to === "distribution") {
                updateYAxis(dataContinuousGroups[0].data.concat(dataContinuousGroups[1].data).concat(dataContinuousGroups[2].data), 0);
                updateXAxis("continuous", duration);

                areas
                    .data(dataContinuousGroups)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                        .attr("d", function(d) {
                            var gen = d3.line()
                                .x(function(p) {
                                    return xContinuous(p.x);
                                })
                                .y(function(p) {
                                    return y(p.y);
                                });
                            return gen(d.data);
                        });

                thresholdLine
                    .style("opacity", 0);

                g.select(".y.axis")
                    .style("opacity", 0);

                g.select(".y-axis-label")
                    .style("opacity", 0);

            } else {
                y.domain([0, 1]);
                d3.select(".y").transition().duration(duration).call(yAxis);

                updateXAxis("discrete", duration);

                areas
                    .data(dataDiscrete)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                        .attr("d", function(d, i) {
                            let numPts = dataContinuousGroups[i].data.length - 2;
                            var path = d3.path()
                            path.moveTo(xDiscrete(d.x), y(0));
                            for (j=0; j<numPts; j++) {
                                path.lineTo(xDiscrete(d.x) + j*xDiscrete.bandwidth()/(numPts-1), y(d.y))
                            }
                            path.lineTo(xDiscrete(d.x) + xDiscrete.bandwidth(), y(0));
                            return path.toString();
                        });

                thresholdLine
                    .transition()
                    .duration(0)
                    .delay(duration)
                        .style("opacity", 1)
                        .attr("y1", y(opts.threshold))
                        .attr("y2", y(opts.threshold));

                g.select(".y.axis")
                    .transition()
                    .duration(0)
                    .delay(duration)
                        .style("opacity", 1);

                g.select(".y-axis-label")
                    .transition()
                    .duration(0)
                    .delay(duration)
                        .style("opacity", 1);
            }
        };


        // Add buttons

        //container for all buttons
        var allButtons = svg.append("g")
          .attr("id", "allButtons");

        //fontawesome button labels
        var labels = ["B", "D"];

        //colors for different button states
        var defaultColor = "#E0E0E0";
        var hoverColor = "#808080";
        var pressedColor = "#000000";

        //groups for each button (which will hold a rect and text)
        var buttonGroups = allButtons.selectAll("g.button")
          .data(labels)
          .enter()
          .append("g")
          .attr("class", "button")
          .style("cursor", "pointer")
          .on("click", function(d, i) {
            updateButtonColors(d3.select(this), d3.select(this.parentNode));
            d3.select("#numberToggle").text(i + 1);
            if (d === "D") {
                toggle("distribution", transDuration);
            } else {
                toggle("discrete", transDuration);
            }

          })
          .on("mouseover", function() {
            if (d3.select(this).select("rect").attr("fill") != pressedColor) {
              d3.select(this)
                .select("rect")
                .attr("fill", hoverColor);
            }
          })
          .on("mouseout", function() {
            if (d3.select(this).select("rect").attr("fill") != pressedColor) {
              d3.select(this)
                .select("rect")
                .attr("fill", defaultColor);
            }
          });

        var bWidth = 40; //button width
        var bHeight = 25; //button height
        var bSpace = 10; //space between buttons
        var x0 = 20; //x offset
        var y0 = 10; //y offset

        //adding a rect to each toggle button group
        //rx and ry give the rect rounded corner
        buttonGroups.append("rect")
          .attr("class", "buttonRect")
          .attr("width", bWidth)
          .attr("height", bHeight)
          .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return x0 + (bWidth + bSpace) * i;
          })
          .attr("y", y0)
          .attr("rx", 5) //rx and ry give the buttons rounded corners
          .attr("ry", 5)
          .attr("fill", defaultColor);

        //adding text to each toggle button group, centered
        //within the toggle button rect
        buttonGroups.append("text")
          .attr("class", "buttonText")
          .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return x0 + (bWidth + bSpace) * i + bWidth / 2;
          })
          .attr("y", y0 + bHeight / 2)
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
          .attr("fill", "white")
          .text(function(d) {
            return d;
          });

        function updateButtonColors(button, parent) {
          parent.selectAll("rect")
            .attr("fill", defaultColor);

          button.select("rect")
            .attr("fill", pressedColor);

        }

        toggle("distribution", 0);

        setTimeout(() => {
            toggle("discrete", transDuration);
        }, 1000);

      },



      resize: function(width, height) {

        // TODO: code to re-render the widget with a new size

      }

    };
  }
});
```

Once I save the svg in the right folder, I'm also not sure how can I use it to replace the two buttons that I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will probably be easiest and most self contained to grab the svg paths (and in this case a rect) and attach them to the svg with `svg.append("defs")` - no need to access any image file from the script. Inserting an svg straight from a file makes it trickier, for example, to color, `.attr("fill",)` won't work in this case.

Open the icon in a text editor, the data we want from the icon is:

```
<path d="M37.92,42.22c3.78-8,7-14.95,12.08-14.95h0c5,0,8.3,6.93,12.08,14.95,6.12,13,13.73,29.13,33.48,29.13h0v-2h0c-18.48,0-25.79-15.51-31.67-28C59.82,32.74,56.3,25.28,50,25.28h0c-6.3,0-9.82,7.46-13.89,16.09-5.88,12.47-13.19,28-31.67,28h0v2h0C24.18,71.35,31.8,55.2,37.92,42.22Z"/>
<rect y="72.72" width="100" height="2"/>
```

Then we can append them to the svg as defs, using a parent g, with:

```
var symbol = svg.append("defs")
      .append("g")
      .attr("id","bellcurve");

    symbol.append("path")
      .attr("d", "M37.92,42.22c3.78-8,7-14.95,12.08-14.95h0c5,0,8.3,6.93,12.08,14.95,6.12,13,13.73,29.13,33.48,29.13h0v-2h0c-18.48,0-25.79-15.51-31.67-28C59.82,32.74,56.3,25.28,50,25.28h0c-6.3,0-9.82,7.46-13.89,16.09-5.88,12.47-13.19,28-31.67,28h0v2h0C24.18,71.35,31.8,55.2,37.92,42.22Z" )

    symbol.append("rect")
     .attr("y", 72.72)
     .attr("width",100)
     .attr("height",2);
```

To use the icon, we only need to append it as a child of a g element (this allows us to scale it too, and since it's width is 100 pixels, this allows for easy scaling to any width:

```
svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform","scale(0.4)")
   .append("use")
   .attr("xlink:href","#bellcurve")
```

Like any other svg element, we can set the stroke, fill, and stroke-width attributes. If setting the stroke-width to more than 2, you probably won't need to set the fill: the stroke will overlap it.

Here's a quick demonstration using your icon, scaling it and coloring it, and for fun, transitioning it:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 400);

var symbol = svg.append("defs")
  .append("g")
  .attr("id","bellcurve");
   
symbol.append("path")
  .attr("d", "M37.92,42.22c3.78-8,7-14.95,12.08-14.95h0c5,0,8.3,6.93,12.08,14.95,6.12,13,13.73,29.13,33.48,29.13h0v-2h0c-18.48,0-25.79-15.51-31.67-28C59.82,32.74,56.3,25.28,50,25.28h0c-6.3,0-9.82,7.46-13.89,16.09-5.88,12.47-13.19,28-31.67,28h0v2h0C24.18,71.35,31.8,55.2,37.92,42.22Z" )
   
symbol.append("rect")
  .attr("y", 72.72)
  .attr("width",100)
  .attr("height",2);
   
svg.append("g")
  .append("use")
  .attr("xlink:href","#bellcurve")
  .attr("fill","steelblue")
  .attr("stroke","steelblue")

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform","translate(100,0)scale(0.5)")
  .append("use")
  .attr("xlink:href","#bellcurve")
  .attr("fill","steelblue")
  .attr("stroke","steelblue")
  .attr("stroke-width",2)

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform","translate(100,50)scale(0.5)")
  .append("use")
  .attr("xlink:href","#bellcurve")
  .attr("fill","steelblue")
  .attr("stroke","steelblue")
  .attr("stroke-width",5)
  
var transition = function() {
  d3.select(this)
  .transition()
  .attr("stroke","orange")
  .attr("fill","orange")
  .duration(1000)
  .transition()
  .attr("stroke","steelblue")
  .attr("fill","steelblue")
  .duration(500)
  .on("end",transition)
}

d3.selectAll("g").selectAll("use")
  .each(transition);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

With that it should be fairly easy to append the image straight to a button. And when toggling which visualization is showing, you can toggle the button's fill.

Slick looking app by the way.